# Show save button after the form's submit on xeditable angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, x-editable

I'm using [xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table) angular directive.Could you tell me how to show the `save` button after the form's submit ? At this moment when we click the `save`it goes to the `Edit` mode.That is the default behaviour.So I need to override it.That is I need to stop it and show the `save` button.Thanks in advance.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sampath_lokuge/NfPcH/9310/)**

```
<form editable-form name="tableform" onaftersave="saveTable()">
  //Ui code here
  <button type="submit" ng-disabled="tableform.$waiting" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>
 </form>
```

***UPDATE***

Actually my use case is where I need to show the `spinner` until finish the form's submit.After that I'll close the whole form (this is a modal popup on my app).That's why I need to stay on that page.I'm going to show the `spinner` on top of the `Save` button.

Answer (score 0):

In your code ***submit*** is on form level not at row level.

So, you have pass your validation which is ***checkName()*** function in your case (you can try by commenting it), then only it will call **saveTable()** function.

Or you can put your ***saveTable()*** in row level.

Comment: Sorry,I couldn't get what you told.I just need to stay on the `Save` button when we `submit` the form.At this moment it goes to `edit` mode.That is the default behaviour.So I need to override it.

Answer (score 0):

Your save button is inside a conditional tag that is only displayed on edit mode.
You may append it into the `.btn-edit` like:

```
<div class="btn-edit">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-show="!tableform.$visible" ng-click="tableform.$show()">edit</button>
    <button type="submit" ng-show="!tableform.$visible" ng-disabled="tableform.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary">save overall</button>
</div>
```

Take a look that using the [form controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) you may check if the entire form is valid or not

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/9303/)

Comment: Can't we stay on the same mode after form's submit ?

Comment: The second save button is for the edit mode inside the editable table.
But I assume that you want to submit the whole form right?

Comment: Actually my use case is where I need to show the `spinner` until finish the form's submit.After that I'll close the whole form (this is a modal popup on my app).That's why I need to stay on that page.

Comment: I'm going to show the `spinner` on top of the `Save` button.